# FFMPEG android compile error

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, makefile

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg for android using ndk. os:ubuntu 13.10. I followed [this](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) tutorial. but when i run the build_android.sh it gives me the following errors-

```
sujith@Vaio:~$ cd /home/sujith/ndk9d/sources/ffmpeg
sujith@Vaio:~/ndk9d/sources/ffmpeg$ sudo chmod +x build_android.sh
[sudo] password for sujith: 
sujith@Vaio:~/ndk9d/sources/ffmpeg$ ./build_android.sh
/home/sujith/sujith/ndk9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-         x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:53: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:95: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:178: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:53: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:95: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:178: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:53: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:95: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:178: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
```

here is my build_android.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=$HOME/sujith/ndk9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
function build_one
{
 ./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

my build_android.sh is located in ffmpeg source root directory.
how to fix this ? please help me..

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android may be helpful.

Comment: same error. used ndk32 and ndk64.

Comment: What's error in the config.log?

Comment: last lines------home/sujith/sujith/ndk9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Os -fpic -marm -mcpu= -c -o /tmp/ffconf.dx5wkTvH.o /tmp/ffconf.2XeLIJ8r.c
./configure: 776: ./configure: /home/sujith/sujith/ndk9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: not found
C compiler test failed.

Comment: on 32bit ndk i have changes linux-x8‌​6_64 to linux-x8‌​6

Comment: Please ensure this file exists and executable: /home/sujith/sujith/ndk9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x8‌​6_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

Comment: yes arm-linux-androideabi-gcc exists and it's executable

Comment: The error message says "... not found C compiler test failed", you may try to run the command above manually and see what happens.

Comment: OK build is successful. now i want to modify the build script to generate libs for all android supported cpu architectures. any idea??

Comment: I got same error how i'll solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, `NDK=$HOME/sujith/ndk9d` is wrong. It should, probably, read

```
NDK=$HOME/ndk9d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I had the same problem , and i dig into it and found that.
#!/bin/bash
NDK=$HOME/sujith/ndk9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

Step 1  : Verify all the above path. 
Step 2 :  Remove all the escape sequence and carriage return like below

#!/bin/bash

NDK=$HOME/FFMPEG/android-ndk/

SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/

TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

function build_one

{
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-avdevice --disable-doc --disable-symver --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-cross-compile --sysroot=$SYSROOT --extra-cflags=-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS --extra-ldflags=$ADDI_LDFLAGS $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG 
make clean
make
make install
}

CPU=arm

PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/work

ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one




Step 3 : As i can see in the your terminal 
sujith@Vaio:~/ndk9d/sources/ffmpeg , you have kept the code in here . 
But i have copied the source code directly in folder sources/ 
I didn't put the code inside any other folder. ./Configure file and build_android.sh are present in the sources/ folder with libavcodec etc folder and code. 

Please try this and let me know if it solves your problem
```